# Retrieving a specific rows data from an html table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have the working code here that displays a table of users stored in my Oracle database:

```
<div id="users_table">

                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>User ID</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Joined</td>
                        <td>Profile</td>


                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${users}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${row.user_id}</td>
                            <td>${row.f_name} ${row.l_name} </td>
                            <td>${row.username}</td>
                            <td>${row.email}</td>
                            <td>${row.joined}</td>
                            <td><a href=#>View</a>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is view a single users portfolio by clicking the "View" href. I need to somehow retrieve the information from that particular row so that I can put it into a Query and display all that particular users data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make the anchor point to some servlet (passing the `user_id` as a parameter) that retrieves that particular row from the database.

Comment: The `a` in `<a href=...>` is called an anchor.

Comment: Ohh okay that makes sense, how exactly would it be able to retrieve say the user_id from that particular row?

Comment: Using `request.getParameter()`. You should read an introductory tutorial to HTTP and the servlet API.